# How to solve this integral over the specific curve and region?

Tags: integration, calculus

Integrate the general expression
$$\int_{x0}^x \int_{y0}^y  \frac{\nabla^{2}\Lambda (\chi ',\psi ')}{\nabla\psi '\nabla\chi '}d\chi 'd\psi '$$ in the curve from $(x0,y0)\to(x0,y)\to(x,y)$, working with the function $\Lambda (\chi ',\psi ')$ in the general form and not by replacing it with an arbitrary function of your choice (see figure)

[image]

and how dows this integral change with the presence of a magnetic field, Bz(x,y)=$\nabla$ x A(x,y) which is derived from the Maxwell equation and the gauge equation between vector A(x,y) and scalar potential Λ(x,y) ($\nabla$Λ(x,y)=A(x,y))

Comment: I tried transcribing your equation, but you seem to missing the differentials (presumably $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$, judging by the limits).

Comment: Please fix the notation and explain why this has something to do with physics.

Comment: I don’t see why this was migrated here from physics.SE. The second part can only be understood if you know the theory of electromagnetism. Is there a way to reject the migration?